# No module Named Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am writing a program in python and it came back with this error. I have tried the solutions from other questions but none of them work for me hence why am asking again. I am using python on the Raspberry Pi running Rasbian.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Docs/rc/serial transmit.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Subprocess
ImportError: No module named Subprocess
>>>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can get me subprocess back :)

Comment: I think it's `import subprocess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to use proper case for identifiers in python. Subprocess and subprocess are two different modules from python's point of view, and only second one is a part of standard library. Variables are also case sensitive in Python. And since you're using raspberry pi I would add that case sensitivity also applies to Unix filesystems. So, that should work:

```
import subprocess
```

Comment: sorry yes you are right, I have been doing this for too long today, making silly mistakes. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

[`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is not capitalized. Try

```
import subprocess
```